# $A$ is the moore penrose of $A^+$: $(A^+)^+ = A$

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, pseudoinverse

$A^+ =VS^+ U^H$
but I think rather than using the definition, I shall use this: $AA^+A = A$ and $A^+=A^+AA^+$
where $A$ is $mn$ matrix.
however my trying ended up  complete mess. I start with $(A^+)^+$ and end up proving that $(A^+)^+=(A^+)^+$.

same with proving $(A^+)^T=(A^T)^+$
I'm stuck in a circle. please any hints will greatly help!

Comment: The conditions $AA^+A = A$ and $A^+ = A^+AA^+$ are not sufficient to completely define the Moore Penrose inverse

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Definition), the definition of $A^+$ is the unique matrix $B$ that satisfies:

1. $ABA = A$,
2. $BAB = B$,
3. $AB$ is Hermitian,
4. $BA$ is Hermitian.

Let $B = A^+$ and $C = B^+ = (A^+)^+$. Then $C$ is the unique matrix that satisfies:

5. $BCB = B$,
6. $CBC = C$,
7. $BC$ is Hermitian,
8. $CB$ is Hermitian.

Note that $C = A$ makes statement 5 equivalent to 2, 6 equivalent to 1, 7 equivalent to 4, and 8 equivalent to 3. That is, $C = A$ satisfies the conditions, and hence $(A^+)^+ = A$.